# Error when creating Publications

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

Here`s a screenshot of error I get when I try to create publication ....
Here's [a link](http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/9452/capturetoh.png)!

What should I do?

*edit*
So now I have problem that I cant delete distributor I created, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because the stored procedure doesn't exist.

Use the SQL Configuration Manager to change the FDHOST Launcher service account or to restart the Filter Daemon host process.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955718)

To change the FDHOST Launcher service/restart the service:

Go **Microsoft SQL Server 2008**, then to **Configuration Tools**, and then click **SQL Server Configuration Manager**. In **SQL Server Configuration Manager**, click **SQL Server 2008 Services**, right-click **MSSQLFDLauncher** , and then click **Properties**.Click the Log On tab of the **SQL Server Full-text Search**  **Properties** dialog box, select This account, and enter the Windows Account Name which you want to use to run the **FDHOST Launcher service**. Click Restart to restart the FDHOST Launcher service.

Comment: OK, but how? :)

Comment: It says now that Distributor is not installed corectly ... I checked and it seams to be fine... :\